# What Mysql uses a lot of CPU

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean, vps

I bough a DigitalOcean droplet year ago. This month I'm receiving high traffic (as I expected) but my page is really slow and occasionally getting 5xx http errors.

Im using Laravel Lumen as API, and Nextjs as frontend. I didn't touch mysql configurations because I don't know any of that I just let it as it comes. I don't know any about mysql configuration.

I think that is Mysql trouble because I ran htop command and saw multiple process of it, and a high CPU consume.

My server has the following specifications:

- 2GB of RAM
- 2vCPUs
- Ubuntu 10.04 (LAMP one-click image)

MysqlTuner report:

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(0B)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[!!] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any warning.
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 0 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 0 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 12.2M (Tables: 33)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 9h 28m 38s (8M q [238.113 qps], 215K conn, TX: 2G, RX: 987M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 1.9G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 2.7G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 176.0M global + 17.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 295.4M (14.82% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.7G (138.10% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/8M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 4% (7/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/215114)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1 temp sorts / 77K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 1M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (8 created / 215K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 96% (224 open / 231 opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(1400) is upper than number of tables(312)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (14/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (102 immediate / 102 locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (3M used / 16M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/43.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 50.0% (6 cached / 3 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/12.2M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 16.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (12270183505 hits/ 12270184226 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 239.53% (103 hits/ 43 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 146 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
```

**Htop**
[image]

Comment: check the mysql server for errors and also check the slow query log, when  you find errors or warnings try to solve them, but even hen a system only can handle a certain traffic, when it exceeds you get 500 errors and it is time to increase the hardware power, but this is more a questions for servers

Comment: Sorry @RiggsFolly I added more info.

Comment: that is strange error.log contains alsways entries

Comment: I checked it and it's fully empty.

Comment: Please post TEXT result from MySQL Command Prompt  SELECT @@log_output;  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck It just return a row called "FILE", no more than that

Comment: Omar, Your error log should contain information from last instance start.  My next comment will request additional information, so we can sort out why you have no information in your error log.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @OmarUreña  Any chance you could post Additional information requested on Sep 6 at 12:26?  Thanks